# Remove Div From a WebView using JSoup

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to remove a div by "class" from webview using JSoup. There are too many examples for remove it "by div id" but i can't find an answer for "by div class". Please tell me how can i do. What I'm trying to do is remove  from webview. Thanks in advice.

This is div part

```
<div id='wrap_all'>
     <div class='mobil-logo'>
    <a href="http://www.isvecehliyet.se/mobil"><img width="250" height="100" title="Isvec Ehliyeti Teori Sorulari" alt="Isvec Ehliyeti Teori Sorulari" src="http://www.isvecehliyet.se/wp-content/themes/isvecehliyet/images/layout/isvec-ehliyet-logo.png" style="max-height: 100px;"></a>
    </div></div>
```

This is a part of my MainActivity

```
mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 mWebview.loadUrl(mUrl);
 public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                mRefreshPbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mRefreshBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                updateActionView();
            }
```

This is for by id code but i don't know how to remove it by class as i said

```
try {

doc = Jsoup.connect("http://isvecehliyet.se/mobil").timeout(100000).get();
 } catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 //get total document

Elements alldivs=doc.select("div");
 ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();

for(org.jsoup.nodes.Element e: alldivs)
 {
 if(!e.id().equals(""))
 list.add(e.id());
 }
 //removing all <div> without "div2"
 for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
 {
 if(!list.get(i).equals(primeDiv))
 doc.select("div[id="+list.get(i)+"]").remove();
 }

html=alldivs.outerHtml();

return null;
 }
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

super.onPostExecute(result);
 webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,doc.html(),
 "text/html", "utf-8", null);

}
```

Comment: Where's your attempt code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following would work

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://isvecehliyet.se/mobil").timeout(10000).get();

doc.getElementsByClass("mobil-logo").first().remove();
```

Comment: I tried a solution without JSoup on onPageFinished() method, isn't it true ?       

mWebview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +  
            "document.getElementsByClass('mobil-logo')[0].style.display = 'none'; " +  
            "})()");

Comment: You should try to avoid navigating to javascript code in order to do operations that Jsoup already has ready and easy like I showed. Try to stay away from hacks like that.

Answer (score 1):

OK I solved it. On onPageFinished() Method I used this;

```
mWebview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +  
            "document.getElementsByClassName('mobil-logo')[0].style.display = 'none'; " +  
            "})()");
```

but I still don't know what should I do if I want to hide one more div.